# Connection to MSSQL from PHP Framework Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm trying to connect a php application (using framework Kohana) with Microsoft SQL Server and It fails!!!

---

**Technical Context:**

- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
- Framework Kohana v2.3.4.
- XAMPP Server v1.7.1:

  - Apache v2.2.11.
  - PHP 5.2.9.
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Express Edition).
- Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0.20219.42000.

---

**Problem Summary:**

- Apparently, the mssql driver is OK! I checked if the folder "...\xampp\php\ext\" has "php_mssql.dll" and if there are a reference with it in php.ini file... and yes!!! Everything are Ok!
- I don't have any authentication problem in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (I'm using a SQL Server Authentication).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnqKR.png)
- I have problems in the Kohana database configuration (I'm using the same authentication data of Management Studio). Where I added the following:

$config['testing'] = array
    (
     'benchmark'     => TRUE,
     'persistent'    => TRUE,
     'connection'    => array
     (
      'type'     => 'mssql',
      'user'     => 'username',
      'pass'     => 'password',
      'host'     => 'SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS',
      'port'     => FALSE,
      'socket'   => FALSE,
      'database' => 'database_name'
     ),
     'character_set' => 'utf8',
     'table_prefix'  => '',
     'object'        => TRUE,
     'cache'         => FALSE,
     'escape'        => TRUE
    );

But, the web browser answer is "mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server:  SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS".

- I tried changing the hostname (I think that the problem is there): without '\SQLEXPRESS' and using the machine IP address.
- I tried setting FALSE the user and pass attributes in the kohana database configuration.

It's important to say: this machine is a testing server! I could connect the application with a sql server in a development machine. So, I tried to connect the development machine application with the testing machine database server and I got the same error. The unique technical differences between the testing and development machines are in the development machine I'm using SQL SERVER 2016 and Windows 10. In the development machine I authenticate in the Management Studio with the "Windows Authentication" and I set FALSE the user ans pass in the kohana database configuration.

What is it could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: So, if you connect from Management Studio using `SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` and your windows credentials, you can log into the server, right?

Comment: @Hackerman: Yes! I don't have any authentication problem in the Management Studio. The problem is in the PHP Kohana.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you are using SQL Server Express 2016 and that your current php driver don't support it....maybe if you update them https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: @Hackerman I'm using SQL Server Express 2012 in the testing machine (where I have problems) and SQL Server 2016 (no Express) in the development machine (where I don't have any type of problems). But yes, I'm going to do the thing that you said.

Comment: @Hackerman this is a very old application. The kohana version that use is v2.3.4 (the newest one is v3.3), this version is not compatible with new ms sql server drivers. Only uses a driver version that (currently) is not supported for new php versions, for that reason I'm using PHP 5.2.9.

I remember some time ago, where I tried to use a new php version and I got problems with the drivers, because It was very new.

Comment: @Hackerman In the development machine I use these old version of php and driver with SQL Server 2016... And I didn't get problems! In the testing machine, where I have problems) the SQL server is older (2012).

Comment: And if you copy the drivers from the dev machine to the testing machine?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I'd done it! And doesn't works! I can say that I tried to connect the application in the dev machine (where everything it's ok) with the sql server in the testing machine and doesn't work.

Comment: @Hackerman What do you think about that I pinged (in the command prompt) "SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS" and It couldn't find it, But If I pinged "SERVERNAME", It find it ??? That is Ok?

Comment: Yes, it's ok...maybe there is some kind of port or configuration that's missing

Comment: @Hackerman The solution was set the filestream properties (in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right click on SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> Properties -> FILESTREAM), enabling filestream for Transact-SQL and file IO accesses and allowing remote clients access to FILESTREAM data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is set the filestream properties (in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right click on SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) -> Properties -> FILESTREAM), enabling filestream for Transact-SQL and file IO accesses and allowing remote clients access to FILESTREAM data.